# React (MERN): Component updates in the database but not in state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state, mern, react-props

When trying to update a component, it successfully updates in the database but the state does not update.

Home.js

```
import { useEffect } from "react"
import { useWorkoutsContext } from '../hooks/useWorkoutsContext'

// components
import WorkoutDetails from '../components/WorkoutDetails'
import WorkoutForm from "../components/WorkoutForm"

const Home = () => {
  const { workouts, dispatch } = useWorkoutsContext()

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWorkouts = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch('/api/workouts')
        if (!response.ok) {
          throw new Error('Network response was not okay')
        }
        const json = await response.json()
        dispatch({ type: 'SET_WORKOUTS', payload: json })
      } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching workouts: ', error)
      }
    }
    fetchWorkouts()
  }, [dispatch])

  const handleUpdateSubmit = (updatedWorkoutData) => {
    console.log(updatedWorkoutData)
    // Update the local state with the updated workout
    const updatedWorkouts = workouts.map((workout) =>
      workout._id === updatedWorkoutData._id ? updatedWorkoutData : workout,
    );
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_WORKOUTS', payload: updatedWorkouts });
  }

  return (
    <div className="home">
      <div className="workouts">
        {workouts &&
          workouts.map((workout) => (
            <WorkoutDetails
              key={workout._id}
              workout={workout}
              onUpdate={handleUpdateSubmit} // Pass the update handler to WorkoutDetails
            />
          ))}
      </div>
      <WorkoutForm />
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

WorkoutDetails.js

```
import { useWorkoutsContext } from '../hooks/useWorkoutsContext'
import React, { useState } from 'react';

// date fns
import formatDistanceToNow from 'date-fns/formatDistanceToNow'

const WorkoutDetails = ({ workout }) => {
  const { dispatch } = useWorkoutsContext()
  const [isUpdating, setIsUpdating] = useState(false);
  const [updatedWorkout, setUpdatedWorkout] = useState({
    title: workout.title,
    load: workout.load,
    reps: workout.reps
  })

  const handleDeleteClick = async () => {
    const response = await fetch('/api/workouts/' + workout._id, {
      method: 'DELETE'
    })
    const json = await response.json()

    if (response.ok) {
      dispatch({type: 'DELETE_WORKOUT', payload: json})
    }
  }

  const handleUpdateClick = () => {
    setIsUpdating(true);
  };

  const handleInputChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target
    setUpdatedWorkout({ ...updatedWorkout, [name]: value })
  }

  const handleUpdateSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      const response = await fetch('/api/workouts/' + workout._id, {
        method: 'PATCH',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(updatedWorkout),
      });
  
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Network response was not okay');
      }
  
      const json = await response.json();
      setIsUpdating(false);
      
      dispatch({ type: 'UPDATE_WORKOUT', payload: json });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error updating workout: ', error);
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <div className="workout-details">
      <h4>{workout.title}</h4>
      <p><strong>Load: </strong>{workout.load}</p>
      <p><strong>Reps: </strong>{workout.reps}</p>
      {isUpdating ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleUpdateSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="title">Title:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          name="title"
          value={updatedWorkout.title}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="load">Load:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="load"
          name="load"
          value={updatedWorkout.load}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <label htmlFor="reps">Reps:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="reps"
          name="reps"
          value={updatedWorkout.reps}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
        />
        <button type="submit">Update Workout</button>
      </form>
      ) : (
        <>
          <p>{formatDistanceToNow(new Date(workout.createdAt), { addSuffix: true })}</p>
          <span className='material-symbols-outlined' onClick={handleDeleteClick}>delete</span>
          <button className='update-btn' onClick={handleUpdateClick}>Update</button>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default WorkoutDetails
```

WorkoutContext.js

```
import { createContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const WorkoutContext = createContext()

export const workoutsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SET_WORKOUTS':
      return {
        workouts: action.payload
      }
    case 'CREATE_WORKOUT':
      return {
        workouts: [action.payload, ...state.workouts]
      }
    case 'DELETE_WORKOUT':
      return {
        workouts: state.workouts.filter((w) => w._id !== action.payload._id)
      }
    case 'UPDATE_WORKOUT':
      return {
        ...state, 
        workouts: state.workouts.map((workout) =>
          workout._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : workout
        ),
      }
    default: 
      return state
  }
}

export const WorkoutsContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(workoutsReducer, {
    workouts: null
  })

  return (
    <WorkoutContext.Provider value={{...state, dispatch}}>
      { children }
    </WorkoutContext.Provider>
  )
}
```

useWorkoutsContext.js

```
import { WorkoutContext } from "../context/WorkoutContext";
import { useContext } from "react";

export const useWorkoutsContext = () => {
  const context = useContext(WorkoutContext)

  if (!context) {
    throw Error('useWorkoutsContext  must be inside an WorkoutsContectProvider')
  }

  return context
}
```

Happy to provide more of my code if needed!

Thanks!

I tried creating a prop called "handleUpdateSubmit" to update the state of a component when it is updated. However, the only way to update is through a manual refresh.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have set up a context and reducer to manage the state of your workouts, which is a good approach. From your code, it looks like the logic for updating the workout in the state is correct.

The issue might be related to how you are passing the onUpdate prop to the WorkoutDetails component. Let's double-check a few things:

In your Home.js, ensure that you are passing the onUpdate prop correctly:

```
{workouts &&
  workouts.map((workout) => (
    <WorkoutDetails
      key={workout._id}
      workout={workout}
      onUpdate={handleUpdateSubmit} // Pass the update handler to WorkoutDetails
    />
  ))}
```

In your WorkoutDetails.js, use the onUpdate prop to trigger the update:

```
const WorkoutDetails = ({ workout, onUpdate }) => {
  // ...
  
  const handleUpdateSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  
    try {
      // ... (your update logic)
  
      // Call the onUpdate function passed from Home.js
      onUpdate(updatedWorkoutData);
      
      setIsUpdating(false);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error updating workout: ', error);
    }
  };
  
  // ...
}
```

Make sure that onUpdate is correctly called after a successful update. If everything is set up correctly, updating the state should work.